# Checking for existence of an item in the collection from Turn State, in Microsoft Bot Framework's If BoolExpression Condition-what expression to use?

Tags: bots, botframework

We are using Microsoft Bot Framework 4.12, C#, .NET Core 3.1 as part of a conversational bot implementation.

Trying to access a collection in turn state in a If condition memory expression (BoolExpression).  Tried the "contains(turn.orderids, 2)" in the Condition expression - but it is not resolving with the turnstate shown in the figure.  Any thoughts on the expression to use?  Clearly I am not using the correct expression.

Thank you

Athadu

```
new IfCondition()
{
    Condition = "contains(turn.orderids, 2)",
    Actions = new List<Dialog>()
    {
        new SendActivity("Order 2 found"),
    },
    ElseActions = new List<Dialog>
    {
        new SendActivity("Order 2 NOT found"),
    }
},
```

[image]

Comment: I tried ```Condition = "contains(orderids, 2)",``` too. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Is this a code-first bot using the SDK or is it built using BotFramework Composer? I'm guessing code-first. Also, can you post more of your code showing where `orderids` is being assigned and where the `IfCondition` is being called? If it's easier, you can send your project to the email listed in my profile.

Comment: It is not using the Composer.  Yes - coded manually - using Adaptive Dialogs.  Unfortunately, the code is not in a shape I can share.  The screenshot I shared is from a break point I sent in the debugger from a code action, right before it hits the if condition

Comment: I ask as Adaptive Dialogs were never meant for use in a code-first bot. It was included in the SDK as Composer relies on it internally for constructing bots designed by the user via its interface. I have this on good authority from the SDK developers, directly. In their words, "if you are a glutton for punishment, then use Adaptive Dialogs." The strong recommendation is to use the methods described in the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) and [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples), as best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "=contains(turn.orderids, 2)"? Note the = sign before the condition.

Comment: hmm.. No - that didn't work with ```Condition = "=contains(turn.orderids, 2)",``` @JohnKim